# Can you explain lambda expressions?

Tags: delegates, lambda, closures, imperative-languages

I don't really *get* lambda expressions. While they've been around since the days of ALGOL, I didn't start hearing about them until fairly recently, when Python and Ruby became very popular. Now that C#  has the `=>` syntax, people in my world (.NET) are talking about lamdba expressions more and more.

I've read the Wikipedia article on the lambda calculus, but I'm not really a math guy. I don't really understand it from a practical perspective. When would I use lambda expressions? Why? How would I know that it's what I should be doing?

Can you show examples of how you would solve problems with lambda expressions, in a before-and-after format? Any imperative language is fine, but C# would be easiest for me to understand.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically as far as C# is concerned, lambda expressions are an easy way to create a delegate (or an expression tree, but let's leave those aside for now).

In C# 1 we could only create delegate instances from normal methods.
In C# 2 we gained anonymous methods.
In C# 3 we gained lambda expressions, which are like more concise anonymous methods.

They're particularly concise when you want to express some logic which takes one value and returns a value. For instance, in the context of LINQ:

```
                       // Only include children - a predicate
var query = dataSource.Where(person => person.Age < 18) 
                       // Transform to sequence of names - a projection
                      .Select(person => person.Name);
```

There's a fuller discussion of this - along with other aspects - in [my article on closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

Comment: that code is looking pretty nice, even though I am pondering if Select is the right name. if you used Map, you'd arrive at relational algebra in code. :)

Comment: To me, Map suggests the creation of a map from key to value, where you can look up by key.

Personally I'd prefer Project().

Comment: There was a brief, tangentially related discussion on Lippert's blog earlier this year about reading the "=>" operator: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/16/reading-code-over-the-telephone.aspx

Answer (score 2):

lambda functions are just anonymous functions.

For example, in python, you want to double all elements in a list. There are pretty much three ways to do so:

List-expressions:

```
[2*x for x in list]
```

explicit function:

```
def double(x):
    return 2*x
map(double, list) # iirc
```

with lambdas:

```
double = lambda x : 2*x
map(double, list)
```

So, a lambda in most languages is just a way to avoid the syntactic overhead of creating a new function.

Comment: Your final comment isn't necessarily true. lambdas provide the ability to create closures over variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

My main use of lambda expressions in .NET has been when working with lists. Using a lambda expression you can build up a query on a list in a similar way as you would build an SQL statement to search a database table.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression is a functional value (in the same sense that 'int' and 'string' are values). This means that it is possible to

- define a variable that holds a lambda expression (this is the same as defining a function)
- return a lambda expression from a method or function
- send a lambda expression as an argument to a function or method

Take a look at functions like map, filter or fold (in any functional language) to see how lambda expressions are used as arguments to other functions.