# How can I get this example using "param" in C# to work?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to understand the meaning and use of the **param** parameter in this line taken from a RelayCommand example:

```
return new RelayCommand(param => MessageBox.Show("It worked."));
```

First, I understand that the "param" parameter has **nothing to do with the "params" keyword**, is this correct?

```
public int Add(params int[] list)
{
  int sum = 0;
  foreach (int i in list)
    sum += i;
  return sum;
}
```

Second, **what kind of delegate code do I have to add** to get the following example to work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestParam222
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}.", Tools.GetTest(param => 23));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Tools
    {
        public static string GetTest(List<int> integers)
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`param` isn't a keyword. It's the parameter for a lambda expression in your sample. You'd need to make your method take a delegate or an expression tree, e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestParam222
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}.", Tools.GetTest(param => 23));
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  class Tools
  {
    public static string GetTest(Func<int, int> integers)
    {
      return "ok";
    }
  }
}
```

The `Func<int,int>` could actually be *any* `Func<T,int>` (or `Func<T,long>` etc) because your lambda expression doesn't use `param` anywhere. Alternatively it could be an `Expression<Func<int,int>>` etc.

I suggest you read up on lambda expressions for more details, for instance in any of these SO questions:

- [Can you explain lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187414/can-you-explain-lambda-expressions-closed)
- [What is a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150129/what-is-a-lambda)
- [C# lambda expression, why should I use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this)