# Lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a situation where the use of the lambda expression is particularly helpful or its mainly usage is to write less code?

Comment: Isn't writing more concise and readable code already particularly helpful?

Comment: Take a look at John Skeet's SO answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187414/can-you-explain-lambda-expressions-closed). And here is another SO question [with specific uses of lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954909/please-list-specific-examples-of-the-benefits-of-using-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Eh eh, sure it is. But I would like to know if it is the only topic... :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The justification for adding lambdas to the language was two things.

(1) They make syntactic transformation of query comprehensions possible.  When you say

```
from customer in customers 
where customer.City == "London" 
select customer
```

That becomes

```
customers.Where(customer=>customer.City == "London")
```

(2) They can be turned into expression trees, and thereby make LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-Entities, and so on, possible. That is, they can represent both *the ability to do their semantics* and *the ability to inspect their structure*.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an expression tree, please? Thanks

Comment: @Eric - You forgot to say "And they're just really cool" ;)

Comment: @Maurizio: http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Lambda expressions are [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28VS.80%29.aspx), and their use cases are mostly the same.

Lambdas can also be converted to expression trees.

As they are much shorter and easier to write (at least for the simple cases), that in itself is helpful.

Comment: I like the expression "syntactic sugar", I didn't know it.

Comment: Not *quite* the same - lambda expressions can also be converted into expression trees, whereas anonymous methods can't. (There's no such term as "anonymous delegate" - there are *anonymous methods*, and *anonymous functions* - that latter is a term covering both anonymous methods an lambda expressions.